# Summary details using php html

Tags: php, html

I want to display multiple PHP outputs to a single HTML page. Here after 1 summary, `script.php` output should be displayed and after 2 summary, `script1.php` output should be displayed. But I'm getting output of PHP after 2 summary.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <h2 align="center">DASHBOARD</h2>
    </head>
    <body>
        <details>
            <summary>1</summary>
            <?php echo file_get_contents("https://servername/script.php"); ?>
        </details>
        <details>
            <summary>2</summary>
            <?php echo file_get_contents("https://servername/script1.php"); ?>
        </details>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there anything in your script.php ? if it's blank then it's display blank

Comment: Hi, yes output is displaying problem is in expanding the details. Both >1 & >2 to be displayed.If we click on these each php output to be displayed.I am getting >1 under these script & >2 script2 output is displaying.

Comment: okay, then use accordion menu. you will find example of accordion menu on google

Comment: This also tried same output its displaying

Comment: provide script.php and script1.php code

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use  [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php),

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will fetch data from the network, so the output will be the same as in your browser (goto https://servername/script1.php and take a look at Page Source)

If your script is located on another server, then, of course, you will not be able to use include, or execute in any way script from other resource.

Comment: Hi, The output should be like this >1 >2  it should be expanded. If we click on 1 it should display script output & if we click on 2 it should display script1 output. Now only one is showing >1 if we click on this it showing >2

Comment: I believe that each of your script have starting and ending <html> tags, so your(any) browser stops to render further after </html>, look at page source.